# What happened to the "hot" button on the questions menu?

Tags: discussion, questions

I only just started using this forum, but I am confused. I liked that there was a button on the question page for "hot" questions (alongside other kinds, like "active" and "featured) here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions

The "hot" button seems to have been replaced with "frequent", and that is different from most other stack forums. Does anyone know why?

Comment: We aren't a forum, a few people fall into that trap and open up perfectly valid forum threads, except that we're on a Q&A site and you need to be able to pick an answer as the correct one for your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still a "hot" tab on the *front page* of the site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot

Note that front page and Questions page are different. Questions page is more "complete" and tailored to search through all of questions on site. Front page is more "current" and about recent activity.

As far as I remember there is also "smart" version of front page which tailors question to *your individual interests* on stack. It is deployed on Stack Overflow (but not sure if any other stacks got it as well).

Comment: duh, thank you!